# is there any non prime (pseudoprime) that holds true for this test, or any prime that fall out of this test?

Tags: polynomials, prime-numbers, sequences-and-series

The sequence is defined by the following formula   $d_{n + 3} = d_{n + 2} + 2d_{n + 1} - d_n$ where $d_1 = 0, d_2 = 1, d_3 = 2$, $\{0, 1, 2, 4, 7, 13, 23,42, ...\}$ if this sequence is calculated over finite field $p$ $$(d_{n + 3} = d_{n + 2} + 2d_{n + 1} - d_n)\,mod\,\text{p}$$ It follows that if $p$ is prime, then the last three terms $d_{p - 1},\; d_p$, and  $d_{p + 1}$ fall within one of the following ending patterns
$\;\{4, 2, 1\}$ , $\{p - 1, 0, 1\}$, or  $\{p - 6, p - 3, p - 2\}$. this is true for all prime up to tested range, $60000$

---

#### my questions

---

1. why only primes follow these patterns?
2. is there any non prime(s) following this patterns?
3. is there any published work like this and in the same pattern. To see if i can study more about it

Comment: There's quite a bit of study about pseudoprimes in linear recurrence relations; see, e.g., [Mathworld's page on Perrin pseudoprimes](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PerrinPseudoprime.html) or [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X10000120) and [this paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1990-55-192/S0025-5718-1990-1035934-2/), both of which purport to give a very broad answer about pseudoprimes in these sequences. Finally, [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2007869?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) seems explicitly germane to the specific question.

Comment: Similar topic, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/291952/is-there-any-pseudoprime-that-pass-this-test-above-tested-range-or-any-prime-th

Answer (score 4):

Prime $p=7$ fails the test, but this is the only exception below $10^7$. This is likely explained by the characteristic polynomial $x^3 - x^2 - 2x + 1$ having discriminant $49=7^2$.

Also, there are nine pseudoprimes below $10^7$: 
$$530881,~ 597871,~ 1152271,~ 3057601,~ 3581761,~ 3698241,~ 5444489,~ 5968873,~ 6868261.$$

Comment: can you please explain further... why?

Comment: I have checked some of the pseudo primes. They are 1 mod 7.  It may be numbers which pass the test and are not prime are required to be 1 mod 7.  You might try for a pseudo prime theorem involving your condition to get necessary conditions on such pseudo primes.  Gerhard "Switch From Inference To Deduction" Paseman, 2018.01.31.

Comment: @EsdrasEEDansha: why what?

Comment: so all pseudo primes fall into 1mod7... right?

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: There are pseudoprimes $\not\equiv 1\pmod{7}$, e.g., $28805713$.

Comment: Indeed. That one is -1 mod 7.  Any others? Gerhard "Believes In Magic Of Seven" Paseman, 2018.01.31.

Answer (score 1):

This should really be just a comment, but I had some technical difficulties.

Consider a number $x$ whose consecutive powers satisfy the recursive formula in the definition of your sequence, that is,
$$x^3=x^2+2x-1.\qquad{(1)}
$$
This equation has three different roots, all of them real. Call them $x_1,x_2,x_3$. Let $a_1,a_2,a_3\in\mathbb{R}$ be arbitrary. For $n\in\mathbb{N}$, define
$$c_n=a_{1}x_{1}^n+a_{2}x_{2}^n+a_{3}x_{3}^n.\qquad{(2)}
$$
Now $c_{n+3}=c_{n+2}+2c_{n+1}-c_{n}$ for all $n$.
On the other hand, given any starting values for $c_1,c_2,c_3$, you can solve for $a_1,a_2,a_3$. So, in particular, there are values for the coefficients $a_1,a_2,a_3$ which give the sequence $(d_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ by the formula $(2)$.

I suggest having a look at equation $(1)$ modulo a number. I'm afraid I haven't yet developed this idea further, so please regard this as a rather long comment.