# Is there any pseudoprime that pass this test above tested range, or any prime that does not show these ending patterns?

Tags: polynomials, sequences-and-series, recurrences

if the recurrence sequence is defined by the following foormula, $d_{n + 3} = 3d_{n + 2} - d_{n + 1} - 2d_n$ where $d_1 = 1, d_2 = 3$ and $ d_3 = 7$, this produce the  following complex sequence $$1, 3, 7, 16, 35, 75, 158, 329, 679, 1392, ...$$.

if this sequence is evaluated over finite field, i mean modulo some interger, $p$
$$(d_{n + 3} = 3d_{n + 2} - d_{n + 1} - 2d_n) \text{mod}\,p$$ It follows that, if $p$ is prime number, the last three term if evaluated up to $n = p + 2$, last three terms i mean $d_{p}, d_{p + 1}$ and $d_{p + 2}$ fall in one of the following ending sequence $\{...,1, 3, 7\}$ or $\{...,4, 7, 14\}$, if $p$ is smaller than these ending patterns, then modulo by $p$. the only exception for prime numbers less than $7$

i have tested all numbers up to $100,000$, no pseudo prime exist

### Prior Studied Sequences

i studied Lucas numbers for existence of pattern like this, but there existed many pseudo prime below $10,000$ e.g $377$. then i studied recussive sequence defined by the following formula $d_{n+3} = d_{n + 2} + 2d_{n + 1} - d_n$. in this sequence pseudo prime exist above $10^6$, may be this sequence can pull up this boundary

### Questions

- is there any pseudo prime above tested range of this sequence
- can anyone explain to me further why this patterns appear to prime only, if mo pseudoprime pass this test

### UPDATES ONE DAY AFTER POST

This update i made after reviewing users comments and answers, thanks to @ Alekseyev for discovering pseudo primes and all other contributions

#### Facts About Pseudo Primes Of This Recurence

- all pseudo primes are divisible by primes. $p_1, p_2,..., p_n$, all of these primes are in the form of $10k + 1$. My limitation is computational power, i can not test big numbers
- all prime factors of these pseudo primes have period of $p - 1$. prime numbers of the form $10k - 1$ also have periods of the form $p -1$. no counter example for other primes having this form of period. if any found?
- if a composite number $n$ have all of its prime factors of this form, $p = 10k + 1$. the resulting period of $n$ get reduced by factor of $10$ and sometimes more than that. the gcd of resultant period $r$ and $n - 1$ is equal to $r$. this explain why $nth$ period occurs at $p - 1$ and the number get evaluated as prime number while not

#### New Update

as we go to the right of number line toward big numbers, things start to deviate from my expectation and all the statement above seem to be invalid, i have found one pseudo prime whose last digit is not $1$, $6368689$ and some prime factors of pseudo primes are not of form $10k + 1$, $16778881$

here is a list of all pseudo prime up to $20 \times 10^6$.

$219781,252601,399001,512461,722261,741751,852841,1024651,1193221,1533601,1690501,1735841,1857241,1909001, 2100901, 2165801,
        2603381, 2704801, 2757241, 3568661, 4504501, 6368689, 6840001, 8341201, 8646121, 8719921, 9863461, 10386241, 10403641, 
        10837321, 12261061, 14609401, 14671801, 16778881$

Comment: $d_4=3d_3-d_2-2d_0$, but you haven't specified $d_0$, so there's no way you can compute $d_4$.

Comment: Previous question was https://mathoverflow.net/questions/291835/is-there-any-non-prime-pseudoprime-that-holds-true-for-this-test-or-any-prime

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Numbers suggest that  it should be $d_{n+3}=3d_{n+2}-d_{n+1}-2d_n$.

Comment: As you increase the degree of your recurrence, incidentally, it should be no surprise that pseudoprimes tend to become rarer.

Comment: @GerryMyerson this is true i made a mistake

Comment: @EsdrasEEDansha: The first assertion in the update is not true as there is pseudoprime $1024651 = 19\cdot 199\cdot 271$.

Answer (score 4):

The sequence of pseudoprimes here starts with:
$$219781, 252601, 399001, 512461, 722261, 741751, 852841, 1024651, 1193221, 1533601, 1690501, 1735841, 1857241, 1909001, \dots$$

**UPDATE**. Efficient testing of a given positive integer $n$ can be done using the formula:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} d_n\\ d_{n+1}\\ d_{n+2}\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
-2& -1& 3
\end{bmatrix}^{~~n-1}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 3\\ 7\end{bmatrix},$$
where computations are performed modulo $n$ (in particular, using [modular exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) of the matrix [by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring)).

Here is my PARI/GP code for the test:

```
test(n) = my(t); t=([0, 1, 0; 0, 0, 1; -2, -1, 3]*Mod(1,n))^(n-1)*[1,3,7]~; t==[4,7,14]~ || t==[1,3,7]~;
```

Comment: i have ruled out all these pseudo primes, read my updates please

Comment: I've read your updates, and have no idea why they rule out these pseudoprimes. But in any event, it's considered bad form to change a question just because you don't like the answer.

Comment: no i havent changed the question but am trying to update it so that someone can contribute from that point. the question is the same brother

Comment: and, is there any method to compute the nth term directy without recussion or loop?

Comment: @EsdrasEEDansha: I've explained how this can be implemented efficiently in the update.